# How to get JOIN data when using ActiveRecord::connection.exec_query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2

I'm building a report and want to do a query and get back an Array of Hash instead of models, for speed purposes.

```
sql = Car.joins(:parts).to_sql
# => "SELECT  `cars`.* FROM `cars` INNER JOIN `parts` ON `parts`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`"

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql).to_a
# => [ { id: 1, ...}, { id: 2, ...} ]
```

This works except but how do I access the association?

I'd like something like `[{ id: 1, parts: { id: 1, ... } }, { id: 2, parts: { id: 2, ... } } ]`

I'm assuming that since ActiveRecord does one query and can provide this data there is a way.

Comment: You must add `includes` to be able to access the join table `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(Car.includes(:parts).joins(:parts).to_sql).to_a`. The `t*` prefix denotes the table. Or you can use select `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(Car.joins(:parts).select('cars.*, parts.*').to_sql)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks, this is a step in the right direction. I looks like I need to transform the output. I bet there is aready something internal to ActiveRecord which does this.

Answer (score 3):

```
sql = Car.select(:id, :brand, 'parts.id AS part_id', 'parts.name AS part_name')
         .joins(:parts)
         .to_sql

results = Car.connection.execute(sql)
results.each_with_object({}) do |row, memo|
  id = row["id"]
  memo[id] ||= {
    id: id,
    brand: row["brand"],
    parts: []
  }
  memo[id][:parts].push({
    id: row["part_id"],
    name: row["part_name"]
  }) unless row["part_id"].nil?
end.values
```

There is a lot going on here but just remember that SQL is tabular so what you get in the results is one row for every part plus the columns from cars:

```
 id |   brand  | part_id | part_name 
----+----------+---------+-----------
  2 | Ford     |       1 | Steeling wheel
  2 | Ford     |       2 | Clutch
  2 | Ford     |       3 | Spark plug
  3 | Volvo    |       4 | Battery
  3 | Volvo    |       5 | Carburetor
# ...
```

Running `$ rails db` and running the queries in a database console and viewing the results as a table is really helpful here.

So with `results.each_with_object({})` we iterate through the result rows while building a hash:

```
{
  # hash key is the same as the id
  2 => {
    id: 2, 
    brand: 'Ford'
    parts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        Steeling wheel
      }
    ]
  }
  3 => {
     # ...
  }
}
```

`.values` converts it into an array. Now all you have to do is benchmark it against just using `.includes` and `.eager_load` and see if its actually worth the fuss.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you go through all this trouble, either you built a query and it returns rows, so arrays (that is what SQL does), or *maybe* you are encountering performance issues rendering pages and want to avoid the N+1 queries, in that case there is a simpler solution: you can eager-load the associations using `includes`, so write

```
cars = Car.includes(:parts)
```

and this will fire two queries: 1 to fetch all the cars, and one to fetch all associated parts (instead of a query per car to fetch all it's parts).

If you do want to use the sql, and not use any of the features in your models (you seem to start from models, but maybe this is for huge reporting/processing), I would adapt your query to order on `cars.id` and then it would be pretty straightforward/easier to convert the received rows (array) to a hash (still it feels like you are doing a lot of work that rails does and loosing a lot of the ease, but then again it make be worth the effort in your specific case).

Comment: Yeah, it a specific case. The report involves a lot of data. I want to avoid the overhead of creating ActiveRecord model instances.

Comment: Are you then looking for answers detailing how to transform the array into a hash? Because you seem to be an experienced programmer and that seems pretty ... Or does it have to be concise/readable, or the most optimal way (time/memory-wise?).